# Multiple users editing the same Spreadsheet, is it possible?

Tags: spreadsheet

I have used a piece of software called Prezi for multiple users to edit a presentation at the same time, I find this a very helpful tool as if lots of data is distributed across a number of minds it can be presented quicker via multiple editors.

is the a way in which I can apply this nature to an Spread sheet document, I know that it will not be possible in Microsoft excel as there are security measures put in place to stop the same document being accessed in the same folder for editing Purposes (I.e. if the document is in use the same document in the same place will open in read only for anyone else).

Is there another spread sheet program that allows for multiple users to log in at the same time in a live environment and edit the spread sheet in real time so that everyone that is editing the document at the time can see it?

On a side note I am wondering if this nature of editing is available for all office programs

Comment: There is a very good reason that Excel shared workbooks don't allow multiple editing, and its not about security. the problem is that these issues (concurrency, race conditions, and data conflicts) cannot be easily handled by a document engine. you will need something that completely abstracts the data source from the users (eg they are no longer looking at a file, which they may have opened 10 minutes ago, but which has changes on the server), in order to achieve what you are looking for. Google docs, as suggested provides that level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com), the Google Sheets application:

> If you’re using Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, Forms, or Drawings, you and others with access to a file can make edits to that file at the same time. In Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Drawings, you’ll be able to see what others are up to keystroke by keystroke, and they’ll be able to see what changes you’re making as you make them.
>
> Real-time collaboration is available only when you and your collaborators are online. If you are working on a file that has been created or modified in "My Drive," you can go back to track activity of that file at a later date to see what changes have been made.

Source: [Google Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494891?hl=en)

Comment: Is this a free service btw?

Comment: @NathanTaylor yes, it is free. You only need a Google Acoount.

Comment: This is very helpful then as my colleagues have already set up Google accounts